# Fgets is ignored when called second time

Tags: c, user-input, fgets

I have a function, that returns true or false, or re prompts based on the user input. Which I retrieve from fgets.

```
BOOL yes()
{

    char ans[4];
    //need to store this somewhere

    fgets(ans,sizeof ans,stdin);


    if(strcasecmp(ans,"yes")== 0 ||strcasecmp(ans,"y") == 0){

        return TRUE;
    }
    else if(strcasecmp(ans,"no")== 0 ||strcasecmp(ans,"n") == 0){
        return FALSE;

    }else{
        printf("Invalid");
       yes();
    }

}
```

This while loop is executed while response returns true,

```
int main(){ 
 do {

        guess();  

        printf("\nDo you want to play again? (yes/no) >");
    } while (yes() == TRUE);
}
```

The guess function also calls yes() like so:

```
void guess(){
    if(yes()){
                  return;
                }


 }
```

When I call yes() in guess, it does prompt for input and return to main as expected, however, as soon as it returns to the main it prints "do you want to play again" and then immediately "Invalid" before I've even gotten the chance to enter any new input?

Comment: Are you using `windows.h`? If so, I think you should use native boolean values instead of Win32's `BOOL`.

Comment: make your buffer bigger; fgets will only consume what fits in the buffer

Comment: newline is included in fgets output. So probably you want `strcasecmp(ans, "yes\n")` and so on.